# Laravel Fortify logout

Tags: laravel, fortify

I have a Laravel 8 Fortify system in place. I have a logout link that looks like this:

```
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                Logout
              </a>
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
        @csrf
      </form>
```

So when I click this logout link, it does not delete logged in session cookies. When I click the back button it just redirects me back to homepage like it is still logged in. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you verified that the session cookies aren't purged? You could use Debugbar, if not. I think that is the browser behaviour that you're experiencing, there. When you click the back button, a cache of the previous page is rendered to reduce unnecessary requests. . I have just checked on a Fortify application that I'm working on and I have the same result, but if I refresh, the middleware redirects me to the login view.

Comment: Exactly, this is the browser cache. It seems stupid tough, that Laravel team did not pay attention to a thing like that because this is an obvious security issue, altough it does not have anything to do with Laravel. If I logout and someone else comes to my computer and clicks the back button, he can go back and see Homepage of my supposedly secure login-register system. I changed header information with a little php script and disabled cache, that solved the issue.

Comment: It could be worth answering your own question and marking it as the correct answer since you found a solution that improves the application's security. It may help somebody in the future

Answer (score 0):

Use this logout button, I think it will solve your problem:

```
<a href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
    {{ __('Logout') }}
</a>
<form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    @csrf
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's not that. I think it's a middleware problem altough I don't see how since I used auth middleware on that route.